# How to exclude a specific UIStackview from semanticContentAttribute .forceRightToLeft change

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I want to some UIViews or UIStackviews stay LTR even after calling this line:

```
UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

(specifically `UIStackViews`)

Comment: then you have to do this manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create A subclass of what you want to stay LTR and set `semanticContentAttribute` for the subclass

```
class MyStackView: UIStackView {
 .
 .
}
```

then :

```
MyStackView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
```